# Subversion branch question

Tags: svn, branch

I have checked out a specific Subversion branch of my app.  Call it '1.0'.  I have been working on some changes, added some new files, etc. but haven't committed the changes yet.  However, I don't want to commit the changes to the '1.0' branch.  Instead, I want to commit my changes to a new '1.1' branch.

As far as I can see I will need to first check out a fresh copy of the '1.0' branch, then create a new Subversion branch called '1.1' and then manually copy my pending changes over before committing.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remote-create a branch, then switch to the new branch and commit the changes.

```
$ cd /path/to/working
$ svn copy svn://my/repos/trunk svn://my/repos/branches/1.1 -m "Created branch 1.1"
$ svn switch svn://my/repos/branches/1.1
$ svn commit -m "Your message"
```

Comment: you may want to copy the branch rather than the trunk in the second line.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually create a branch without having a checked-out working copy at all, using only remote URLs. If you do an `svn copy` of the trunk (or 1.0 branch) to a 1.1 branch, you can then do an `svn switch` to move your working copy to point to the new branch then commit there. (If you haven't done something like this before, it's wise to save a backup of your current working copy so you don't lose your modifications.)

For example...

```
svn copy http://svn.example.com/branches/1.0/ \
         http://svn.example.com/branches/1.1/ \
    -m "Creating 1.1 branch."

cd /path/to/working/copy
svn switch http://svn.example.com/branches/1.1/
```

Take a look at `svn help switch` for more details.

Answer (score 2):

`svn switch` lets you switch your working copy to a different branch. You can create the branch beforehand without checking out a new copy with `svn copy <repository>/branches/1 <repository>/branches/2`